# Do I have to stick around to get co-op loot?

Tags: diablo-iii

I dropped in on a couple co-op games in the beta today and the first thing I noticed was that everyone wasn't running for loot. This is a thing of the past, apparently, as any loot that you can see is yours and yours alone.

That said, is there a limit to when loot drops for me during co-op play? Does it drop when I'm in town or if I'm around but I don't hit an enemy before it's killed?

Comment: Things I can confirm **are** dropped while a player is in town are items from world containers such as weapon racks and dead villagers. Items from monsters do not seem to drop for players who are in town.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I thought your answer was more complete, why delete it?

Comment: It was incomplete and I could not devote the time to completing it.  I converted it to a comment to help future answerers.

Comment: Actually, I've been in town plenty of times. And I've zoned to my buddy. And loot was there that shouldn't of been. So I think this system isn't really complete... That or some loot is given as a *cheers*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loot drops for you only off of those monsters that die within a certain distance of your character.  Bashiok (Diablo 3 CM) confirms this with a tweet ([link](http://twitter.com/#!/Bashiok/status/166765857983307776)).

Comment: It should be noted that treasure chests will drop loot for a player regardless of their location. I once joined a game and when I teleported to someone, there was an open treasure chest with loot on the ground a short distance away for me. Also per [OrigamiRobot](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49377/do-i-have-to-stick-around-to-get-co-op-loot#comment72055_49377), weapon racks and dead villagers behave the same way.